# Does the time you can stay still before being eaten decrease as you progress?

Tags: crossy-road

When playing Crossy Road, if you stay still for a period of time you are eaten by a eagle that comes down and eats you. [This](https://www.gamezebo.com/2014/11/24/crossy-road-tips-cheats-strategies/) article from 2014 states that if you don't move forward in 5 seconds that is when the eagle comes.

As your points increase, does the time needed for the eagle to come decrease? So that say when you pass 200 points your allowed 3 seconds of not moving. Or does it remain 5 seconds, no matter what your points are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I don’t know the exact points it takes before it starts to speed up but over time the screen moves faster